# Is there a better way to ensure ruby's LOAD_PATH doesn't get messed up?

Tags: ruby, load-path

I'm trying to avoid ever adding a redundant path to ruby's `LOAD_PATH`. It's not a remarkably complicated task, I'm just wondering if there is a cleaner method then what I've come up with.

This is my current solution as it stands now:

```
def add_loadpath(new_path)
  included = $LOAD_PATH.inject(false) do |acc,path|
    acc || new_path == File.expand_path(path)
  end
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift new_path unless included
end
```

Then instead of doing the usual `$LOAD_PATH.unshift SOME_PATH` you'd call
`add_loadpath SOME_PATH`

This is to avoid problems when the load path includes two paths that point to the same folder but are not the same string. For example `foo/../bar` and `bar`

Answer (score 0):

I believe all paths in `$LOAD_PATH` are already expanded, so `File.expand_path(path)` is pointless. Your code can be refactored to this:

```
def add_loadpath(new_path)
  File.expand_path(new_path)
  .tap{|new_path| $LOAD_PATH.unshift(new_path) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(new_path)}
end
```

or

```
def add_loadpath(new_path)
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path(new_path)).uniq!
end
```

Comment: you're right that most of the time the `$LOAD_PATH` isn't tainted with relative paths, but there is nothing stopping someone from typing something like this, `LOAD_PATH.unshift '../../bin'` and breaking that convention. I'm trying to eliminate that possibility and also handle the possibility of a relative path.